# How to darw a node with label is '*' using dot (graphviz)?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to draw a node that the node label only displays a char : '*' .

```
digraph {
node2[label="*"];
}
```

But when the image generated, the label displays a empty string. Is that possiable to draw a node only displays a '*' ?

Comment: Works for me - what version of graphviz & platform are you using? The command line which creates the graph, and which output format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
digraph G {
  a [shape="none", label="*"] ;
  b [shape="box", label="*"] ;

  a -> b ;
}
```

Works fine.

Comment: I used this site:http://ashitani.jp/gv/ to draw my digraph. It seems this is a bug that "*" was ignored.